# Floatpag linespacing issue

Tags: floats

I'm attempting to supress page-numbers on pages with very large images and tables. I couldn't get `\afterpage` to work, and so instead am using `floatpag`.

However, the issue I am having is that it applies the linespacing of the document to figure and table captions, as well as table cell spacing, whereas the default uses single line spacing. This wrecks my formatting (and makes the captions very hard to distinguish from the text). Does anyone know how to revert to single linespacing for captions and table cells while still using `floatpag`?

MWE:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\linespread{1.5} % Changing this value also affects captions and table cell spacing
\begin{document}
%Table
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
x & y & z   \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%Figure
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]{big_fig.png}
    \caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has problem, it can be somewhat fixed by altering the caption linespacing after `floatpag` is loaded, like so:

```
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1}}     
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1}}
```

this does not fix the table cell spacing however.